# Segmentation fault using FFTW

Tags: c++, fftw

I have a pretty involving program that uses an in house FFT algorithm. I recently decided to try using FFTW for a performance increase. Just as a simple test to ensure that FFTW would link and run, I added the following code to the beginning of the application, however, when I run, I get a segmentation fault when I create the `fftwf_plan`:

```
const size_t size = 1024;
vector<complex<float> > data(size);
for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) data[i] = complex<float>(i, -i);

fftwf_plan plan =
    fftwf_plan_dft_1d(size,
                      (fftwf_complex*)&data[0],
                      (fftwf_complex*)&data[0],
                      FFTW_FORWARD,
                      FFTW_ESTIMATE);
// ^ seg faults here ^

fftwf_execute(plan);
fftwf_destroy_plan(plan);
```

Any ideas what would be causing this?

Using FFTW 3.3. Tried 2 different compilers, g++ 4.1.1 and icc 11.1. Also, the core file file shows nothing of significance:

```
Thread 1.1: Error at 0x00000000
Stack Trace: PC: 000000, FP=Hex Address
```

**EDIT**

I reconfigured FFTW to add debug, using the following commands:

```
setenv CFLAGS "-fPIC -g -O0"
configure --enabled-shared --enable-float --enable-debug
make
make install
```

When the program has a segmentation fault, it is in a random location in the `fftwf_plan_dft_1d()` method, however, the stack trace allways shows that is in or below the function `search` which is called by `mkplan`.

Comment: You should find out what line it's seg faulting on and then update the question with more information.

Comment: You said this is all in-house code.  That means you can figure out what line of fftwf_plan_dft_1d the seg fault is happening on.

Comment: As soon as it enters `fftwf_plan_dft_1d` the debugger stops all of a sudden with no error or status, and if I examine a core file, it shows nothing.

Comment: Please post the declaration of `fftwf_plan_dft_1d()` and the first lines of its implementation.

Comment: I guess that if `i` is a `size_t`, `-i` won't give you the result you expect. And by looking at the header `fftw3.h`, I see they expect a C99 complex, of something with the same layout. Are  you sure the std::complex has the same layout/is compatible?

Comment: It is fortran code: `type(C_PTR) function fftwf_plan_dft_1d(n,in,out,sign,flags) bind(c,name='fftwf_plan_dft_1d') import integer(C_INT), value :: n complex(C_FLOAT_COMPLEX), dimensions(*), intent(out) :: in` etc. Do you want more?

Comment: At paercebal: I am not looking for any result, that was just a test to see if it would compile and run, the results are useless, I just don't want it to seg fault, and the complex type should be compatible as they are both contiguous memory, `float[2]` and `struct { float re, im; }`

Comment: have you checked if the core file is set to the appropriate size with `ulimit -c(or -a?)`? Sometimes, if the core file size is zero, the core file is not dumped.

Comment: Yes, I have it set to unlimited

Comment: You might need to recompile FFTW with debugging symbols to see what's going on. On Linux-like systems, extract the FFTW-3.3 source distribution, `cd` into the extracted folder, and type `CFLAGS='-g -O0' FFLAGS='-g -O0' ./configure`

Comment: I reconfigured with debug and posted more information in the post. Also, I ran `valgrind` against the app and it wasn't helpful, but did complain in the same areas in FFTW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aparently the issue stems from multi-threading. Even though the main functions are thread safe in FFTW (e.g. `fftwf_execute`), the functions to create a plan are not. This doesn't fully explain why just running a test on startup failed, however, when I excapsulated the plan creation in mutex locks, the segmentation faults ceased.

Comment: I have a trouble when integrating FFTW3 in Apache Spark (with JNI). If I execute my app using a single core per node in cluster mode or a single core in a single machine (local mode), everything is OK. However, If I execute my app by using two or more cores per machine, I found this problem: SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007ff9007bc5ae, pid=27386, tid=0x00007ff91e1f1700 - Problematic frame: C  [libfftw3f.so.3+0x155ae]  fftwf_mkplan+0xe

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit more how to create a mutex lock? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The creation and destruction of plans must be single threaded

```
fftw_init_threads();
#pragma omp parallel for
for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
   #pragma omp critical {
     plan = fftw_create_plan....
   }
   fftw_execute(plan); // or the fftw_execute_dft for multiple in/out fft operations
   #pragma omp critical {
     fftw_destroy_plan(plan);
   }
}
fftw_cleanup_threads();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm 3 years late, but I've just stumbled upon a very similar problem, also when using multi-threading (`--enable-openmp` and `fftw_plan_with_nthreads(omp_get_max_threads())`). Mine seg faulted on `fftw_destroy_plan(p)`.

It turned out that I didn't pay attention when restructuring my code, and I was calling `fftw_cleanup_threads()` before calling `fftw_destroy_plan(p)` ... silly, I know, but it got me chasing my tail for about 1h.

When using multi-threading, `fftw_cleanup_threads()` needs to be called after all fftw* functions, just as `fftw_init_threads()` needs to be called before any fftw* function.

Comment: Hi @normadize, i've been following you around because of the thread you started on the wordpress forums. In a comment, you mentioned that qtranslate-slug could be improved. I'm now also maintaining it, and i'm wondering which changes you made. Sorry, to hunt you down here... :)

Comment: Mods will surely delete this but perhaps you can leave some contact info or write to my gmail address (same name) before they do.