# Storing an array of fftwf_plans?

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, fftw

I'm working on an SDR program, and I have queues of data coming from the RTL2832 dongle, another queue waiting to go through FFTW (in another thread), another queue waiting to be displayed in another thread.

I was using a static array of plans but now I want to switch to a dynamically allocated one.  Like:

```
//fftwf_plan fftplan[NUMFFT];
fftwf_plan *fftplan; // dynamic version
```

Then later I do

```
fftplan = calloc(NUMFFT,sizeof(fftwf_plan));
```

And to fill the array I do:

```
fftplan[i] = fftwf_plan_dft_1d(fftsize,fftin[i],fftout[i],FFTW_FORWARD,FFTW_ESTIMATE);
```

Which now segfaults when it runs and I'm kinda clueless.  I figured out the FFT  part a year or more ago, I'm not up to speed on it.  It works with a static array.  I barely understand ** and now I'm trying to fill a dynamic array with opaque pointers.  I think it's mostly a C question, not an FFT one, but I don't think I can use ** here since it's opaque.

My data is in 2d arrays like

```
fftwf_complex *fftin[NUMFFT], *fftout[NUMFFT];
```

So basic AM demod is like

```
dpybuf[i] = sqrt(((fftout[lochead][i][0]) * (fftout[lochead][i][0])) + \
   ((fftout[lochead][i][1]) * (fftout[lochead][i][1])));
```

Maybe I don't need a separate plan for each bufferful of data.  lochead is the position in the circular queue, i is an individual point, [0] or [1] at the end is the real or imaginary part.

```
-------------- edit------------
```

In doing SDR a radio waveform is digitized by doing 2 A/D conversions 90 degrees apart.  Those are called I and Q and treated as real and imaginary numbers.  There's no actual square root of a negative number.

OK, some more of the code, but the whole thing's a couple thousand lines in several files.

```
fftwf_plan *fftplan; // dynamic version [global]
// I tried **fftplan above, it acts the same: compiles OK but segfaults

fftplan = calloc(NUMFFT,sizeof(fftwf_plan));
if (fftplan == NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr,"Failed to allocate fftplan[]\n");
  exit(1);
}

// fft init  (NUMFFT is set at 10, the # of batches in the queue.)
for (i=0;i<NUMFFT; i++) {
  fftin[i] = (fftwf_complex *) fftwf_malloc(sizeof(fftwf_complex) *  fftsize);
  if (fftin[i] == NULL) {
    printf("malloc() of space for fftin failed.\n");
    perror("malloc ");
    exit(1);
  }
  fftout[i] = (fftwf_complex *) fftwf_malloc(sizeof(fftwf_complex) * fftsize);
  if (fftout[i] == NULL) {
    printf("malloc() of space for fftout failed.\n");
    perror("malloc ");
    fftwf_free(fftin);
    exit(1);
  } 
aplan = fftwf_plan_dft_1d(fftsize,fftin[i],fftout[i],FFTW_FORWARD,\
  FFTW_ESTIMATE);

printf("plan %i\n",i);  // announce progress
fflush(stdout);
    fftplan[i]  = aplan; // see where it segfaults [here, storing plan 0]

  }
```

fftwf is the single precision floating point version of FFTW.  I only have 8 bit samples coming from the dongle, I don't need doubles.

fftsize is now my display X resolution, I was running 4096 points through here, now 1024

Comment: I don't see any obvious problem with the way you're handling your array. Are you sure the segfault is to do with the array?

Comment: I don't know what `fftwf_plan` is. Could it be a typedeffed pointer? In `fftplan = calloc(NUMFFT,sizeof(fftwf_plan));` is `sizeof *fftplan == sizeof(fftwf_plan)`? I would expect so, but that is the only thing unclear about what you have posted. That and `fftout[lochead][i][0])` where are the 3 level of indirection from?

Comment: consider fftwf_plan a pointer that sizeof(fftw_plan)==sizeof(void*), like you said, it is an opaque object. The interesting part would be how you allocate the fftin[i] and fftout[i]? It would be good to post a minimum example that can compile and execute. The NUMFFT, you used it as number of plan or number of data points for transform?

Comment: Well, duh, I broke it up.  I made an fftwf_plan variable, I can set that OK, it's when I try to copy that into the array that I get a segfault.;

Comment: #define NUMFFT 10 // # of fft plans, fft input and output arrays (it's the size of the queue, lochead is the queue position.  lochead is a local var set to the head position in the queue when the mutex is locked). fftwf_complex *fftin[NUMFFT], *fftout[NUMFFT]; then I use fftin[i] = (fftwf_complex *) fftwf_malloc(sizeof(fftwf_complex) *  fftsize);

Comment: This was working: //fftwf_plan fftplan[NUMFFT]; but I wanted a dynamic array so I could change the size easier than #defining NUMFFT in a header.  I don't remember exactly why now but I'm trying to make the program more flexible.  FFTSIZE is now fftsize, set to the X resolution read by an ioctl FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO.  But I switched from static arrays to dynamic without changing anything in the way they're accessed.  In some cases that works right.  The compiler doesn't complain.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer  "However, they will not be able to de-reference such a pointer, and can only change the object's content by calling some procedure that has the missing information."  What happens if I make an array of void * and set those equal the opaque *?  I'll probably need to cast them back as I use them.  Maybe they'll need to be void **.

Comment: Maybe this is relevant : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574350/segmentation-fault-using-fftw  I do have several threads.  Since this stuff is just initialization I'll try moving it to before I init the threads.  And I'm not using fftw_init_threads at all.  http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Usage-of-Multi_002dthreaded-FFTW.html

Comment: Well, maybe not.  I also followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36790241/how-to-setup-fftw-with-threads-and-different-precisions and I think I have the multi-threaded stuff right but my segfault is exactly the same: when I try to store the plan into a dynamic array of them.  There's only one thread doing FFT anyway, and it's on data in a queue protected by a mutex.  Maybe I'll just go back to a static array in this case.